# Can't show Bootstrap searchbar in header properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble when displaying a searchbar in the right side of a header.

What I'm doing is the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="page-header">
            <div class='btn-toolbar pull-right'>
                <div class='btn-group'>
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">

                </div>
            </div>
            <h2>Perfiles</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle to illustrate my problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16632/

EDIT:

Ok, here's a picture with the problem:

[image]

What I want is that both the sarch button and the input are in the same row.

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem?

Comment: @cakan Edited with a more specific explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search input field has `width: 100%` and `display:block`. Fixing that should solve the problem. Try adding following to your CSS:

```
.form-control {
  width: auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16637/).

Comment: I was trying to avoid touching the the .css file. I posted my own question with the answer. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!

The trick was in the use of `class="form-inline"`

Here is the code to make it work:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="page-header">
        <div class='btn-toolbar pull-right'>
            <div class='btn-group'>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">

            </div>
        </div>
        <h2>Perfiles</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the picture of what I was actually looking:

[image]